# Confused about the Hall effect?

Tags: electromagnetism

In the common configuration of the [Hall Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect), why wouldn't the conductor move? 
It follows the same principle of the Lorentz force or basic electric motor doesn't it?

I can't seem to find the difference between them...

Comment: As a Chemist I've long since forgotten about the Hall Effect, however, there is a very good explanation/description in University Physics by Young and Freedman.

Answer (score 2):

There is, of course, a force on the conductor.  It would move if it could.  But, in the Hall experiment it is held still by mechanical forces.  Actually, that is not quite true.  There is a force on the conductor, but (in the usual experiments) the conductor can not move very much because it is a solid wire, attached to other solids all of which have very high elastic moduli. The electrical forces are quite small, so the motion of the conductor is negligible.

Comment: Makes perfect sense!